# How to access object inside array in json file using data-table in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

**JSON data:**

> [{"kContentProcessing":1,"appData":{"kAppData":1,"name":"500px.com"},"owner":"Sup Julius.","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"no","dv_req":"no","iibe_req":"no","createdate":"2015-08-03"},{"kContentProcessing":2,"appData":{"kAppData":2,"name":"9gag.com"},"owner":"amey","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"no","dv_req":"no","iibe_req":"no","createdate":"2015-08-10"},{"kContentProcessing":3,"appData":{"kAppData":3,"name":"abc.go.com"},"owner":"jack","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":4,"appData":{"kAppData":3,"name":"abc.go.com"},"owner":"jill","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":5,"appData":{"kAppData":5,"name":"aliexpress.com"},"owner":"jones","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":6,"appData":{"kAppData":6,"name":"allthecooks.com"},"owner":"Mark","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":7,"appData":{"kAppData":7,"name":"bigoven.com"},"owner":"jons","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":8,"appData":{"kAppData":8,"name":"bookmyshow.com"},"owner":"joes","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":9,"appData":{"kAppData":9,"name":"crackle.com"},"owner":"jnes","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"},{"kContentProcessing":10,"appData":{"kAppData":10,"name":"eat24.com"},"owner":"ones","cp_status":"done","dv_status":"done","iibe_status":"done","cp_req":"done","dv_req":"done","iibe_req":"done","createdate":"2015-08-11"}]

**HTML**:

```
<th data-field=appData.name[0] data-sortable="True" data-align="center" id="o">Name</th>
```

So how can I access name field using `data-field`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can do that by setting `data-column-defs` attribute for `table` element

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" data-column-defs='[{"targets":0,"data":"appData.name"}]'>
```

According to the [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/options):

> There are two important points to consider when using `data-*` attributes as initialization options:
>
> - jQuery will automatically convert from dashed strings to the camel case notation used by DataTables (e.g. use `data-page-length` for `pageLength`).
> - If using a string inside the attribute it must be in **double quotes** (and therefore the attribute as a whole in **single quotes**). This is another requirement of jQuery's due to the processing of JSON data data.

However instead of using `data-` attributes you can use initialization option [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) directly.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxmao9n3/) for code and demonstration.